# How to add a prefix to scss urls in webpack?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I include scss files from packages that contain url() with a relative path, e.g.

```
src: url('./flags/en.svg');
```

How is it possible to add a prefix to this url? E.g. './images'? I don't want to have processCssUrls set to true.

Comment: Why do you need that? Webpack should resolve the paths at compile time. Or do you want to change them before they get resolved?

Comment: I want to organize the image files in the /public folder on my own. So, I need the plugin images come to /public/images  as well.

Comment: Then you need to change the settings for the loader you use for the images, not the scss. Are you using `file-loader`?

Comment: Yes, file-loader. I searched a lot, but didn't find the correct answer. Could you navigate me, please?